# How to find value of each pixel in all the frames of a video using python

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I have a video with dimensions say 1280, 720 and 166 frames. Now I want to track the value of each pixel at a given position. Like at position (100, 100), I want to get the value of the pixel at this position in all the 166 frames. This will give me 166 value.

Likewise I want to find values of pixels at all the positions in the frame.Then fit a curve for all the values of each pixel one by one afterward.

This is code I wrote but this is able to obtain pixel values at the specified position only.

```
cap= cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
success, image = cap.read()
count = 0
while success:
  count += 1
  v = image[500, 700]
  s = sum(v)/len(v)
  print(" Count {}  Pixel at (500, 700) - Value {} ".format(count,v))
  success, image = cap.read()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I also tried using width and height of the frame but it is reading the positions randomly and I want them to be stored in sequence because I want to plot a graph for each of them:

```
while success:
  count += 1
  for x in range(0,width):
    for y in range(0,height):
      print(image[x,y,z])
```

So what changes do I have to make in this code to get all the values.

Comment: I've seen you ask a question like this before. a tutorial for numpy would probably help you a lot.

Comment: I am new to this that is why I am asking questions like these. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cap= cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
success, image = cap.read()
count = 0
while success:
  count += 1
  print("{}th image from the movie ".format(count))
  for x in range(0,1280-1):
      for y in range(0,720-1):
          v = image[y, x]
          print("Pixel at ({}, {}) - Value {} ".format(x,y,v))
  success, image = cap.read()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks! But this code is again giving me the values of pixel at 500, 700. And I want to find the values at all the positions not just one.

Comment: Do you want to get average image?

Comment: Yes and for all the frames individually for each pixel

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer I understood my mistake!

Comment: I am getting this error: IndexError: index 720 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 720
in the line v = image[x, y] after reaching (719, 718) for the first frame

Comment: Please, exchange v = image[x,y] to v = image[y,x]